# C# Update local table object after adding new record using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working with C# and Pgadmin (Database).

Below is my scenario-

I am fetching the "Student" table from db (by using dbContext). And along with that I am fetching/including the table "StudentDepartment", which is the child table of "Student" table. And table "DepartmentType" is the child table of "StudentDepartment".

```
var studentId = 1;
var student = await _dbContext.Students
                      .Include(x => x.StudentDepartments)
                      .ThenInclude(x => x.DepartmentTypes)                    
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == studentId);
```

Now I have to add one new record inside "StudentDepartment" table into the db by dbContext. Like below-

```
await _dbContext.StudentDepartments.AddAsync(new StudentDepartment()
{
    StudentId = student.Id,
    Student = student,                
    DepartmentTypeId = departmentTypeId,  //primary key of DepartmentType table                
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
    UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,               
});

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(true);
```

So, after adding new record into the database (db) for "StudentDepartment" table, the above "student" object should be updated for the new record of "StudentDepartment" table.

Can someone suggest what should be the best way to do that? The above two sections of code's are contain inside one function only. I am using C#.

Comment: what do you want to update for `Student`?

Comment: @viveknuna, Student object should show the newly added record for "StudentDepartment" table.

Comment: Instead of adding the student navigation properties to the `StudentDepartment` object, you could add this new department to the `Student.StudentDepartments` collection. EF should do the fix-up of the id and navigation property automatically on save.